# Botón para ocultar subformulario access

Tags: ms-access

He creado un formulario "Pedidos" con un subformulario dentro asociado llamado "Referencia1".

Oculto el subformulario "Referencia1" cambiando la propiedad "visible = No" porque no me interesa que esté siempre visible.

Para que se muestre cuando yo quiera, en el formulario he colocado un botón de comando en el que he insertado el siguiente código en el evento "al hacer click":

*Me.Referencia1.Visible = True*

Hasta aquí, bien.

Ahora, lo que me gustaría es añadir dentro de este subformulario otro botón que vuelva a ocultar el formulario cuando lo pulso.

Añado el botón de comando en la vista diseño del formulario que contiene el subformulario, selecciono el marco del subformulario y añado en el evento "al hacer click":

*Me.Referencia1.Visible = False*

Pero me salta este mensaje de error en el depurador: "Method or data member not found".

Por lo que leído, no parece difícil de hacer, pero no localizo dónde está el problema.

Os agradecería si pudierais ayudarme.

Trabajo con ms-access 2016

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en tu código es que el botón lo tienes dentro del subformulario e intentas acceder a el con `Me.Referencia1.Visible = False` y ese 'Me' ya es Referencia1 por lo que no encuentra otro Referencia1 dentro.
Esto lo puedes ver poniendo `msgbox(Me.name)` antes.

Tendrías que hacer `Me.Visible = False` para referirte al subformulario.

Pero esto te va a decir que no puede porque tiene el foco, por lo que antes de ocultarlo habrá que pasárselo a otro elemento del formulario principal, dejando el código de ese botón así:

```
Me.Parent.Boton1.SetFocus  'Suponiendo que el botón de "fuera" se llama Boton1'
Forms!Formulario1!Referencia1.Visible = False  'Suponiendo que el formulario se llama Formulario1'
```

De todas formas, no te valdría utilizar el mismo botón de fuera para las dos acciones?

algo así:

```
If Me.Referencia1.Visible = False Then
    Me.Referencia1.Visible = True
    Me.Boton1.Caption = "Cerrar subfomulario"
Else
    Me.Referencia1.Visible = False
    Me.Boton1.Caption = "Abrir subformulario"
```

Comment: Hola, Adrián, gracias por tu respuesta. Preferiría hacerlo con un botón dentro del subformulario porque cuando el subformulario aparece, puede tapar el botón para pulsarlo de nuevo y desconozco cómo mover libremente la ventana subformulario en la vista formulario. Para usar el mismo botón, había utilizado: _me.referencia1.visible=not me.referencia1.visible_, pero no me convence.

Comment: Hola @Ruy, te he puesto esa opción mientras investigaba lo que pedías. Ya he puesto como hacerlo. Dejo también la primera opción que te he dado en la respuesta porque creo que puede ser útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Adrián. Funciona perfectamente. ¿Conoces alguna forma de mover libremente la ventana del subformulario una vez se muestre en la vista formulario?

Comment: Con 'libremente' te refieres a que el usuario pueda arrastrarla o algo así? si es eso, no sé como se haría. Supongo que tendrá que ser otro formulario diferente en vez de un subformulario, pero no estoy seguro, lo siento.